# Firefox pushed up while other browsers push down

Tags: html, css, firefox

When an image gets too large Firefox pushes them up while other browsers push them down (like I want to)

[image: How Firefox does it]

[image: How other browsers do it (and how I want it to work)]

First one is how Firefox does it, the second one is how other browsers do it and how I want it to work. As you notice the second one has the text all on the same line while the first one hasn't.

HTML

```
<div id="trees">
    <div class="tree">
        <img src="http://clipartsy.com/Holidays/Christmas/Xmas/christmas_tree_icon_xmas-1969px.png" width='150' height='186' value='Doel A' />
        <div class="subtext">
            Het vergeten kind
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tree">
            <img src="http://clipartsy.com/Holidays/Christmas/Xmas/christmas_tree_icon_xmas-1969px.png" width='150' height='186' value='Doel B' />
        <div class="subtext">
                Kind en brandwond
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tree">
            <img src="http://clipartsy.com/Holidays/Christmas/Xmas/christmas_tree_icon_xmas-1969px.png" width='150' height='186' value='Doel C' />
            <div class="subtext">
                Kinderen van de Voedselbank
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#trees{
width: 100%;
height: 240px;
}

.tree{
    position: static;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 0;
    height: 186px;
    color: #860037;
    width: 180px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
}

.tree img{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d5044nxk/1/)**

Comment: Two relative divs. Top div put in img, position absolute bottom. Bottom div put in text, positioned absolute top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to `.tree` to align the elements along the top edge rather than the baseline.

```css
#trees{
  width: 100%;
  height: 240px;
}
.tree{
  position: static;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 0;
  height: 186px;
  color: #860037;
  width: 180px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.tree img{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="trees">
    <div class="tree">
        <img src="http://clipartsy.com/Holidays/Christmas/Xmas/christmas_tree_icon_xmas-1969px.png" width='150' height='186' value='Doel A' />
        <div class="subtext">
            Het vergeten kind
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tree">
            <img src="http://clipartsy.com/Holidays/Christmas/Xmas/christmas_tree_icon_xmas-1969px.png" width='150' height='186' value='Doel B' />
        <div class="subtext">
                Kind en brandwond
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tree">
            <img src="http://clipartsy.com/Holidays/Christmas/Xmas/christmas_tree_icon_xmas-1969px.png" width='150' height='186' value='Doel C' />
            <div class="subtext">
                Kinderen van de Voedselbank
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```